# Add specific elements from an NSDictionary to an NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I have this NSDictionary `itemsDict`(in Swift):

```
var itemsDict : NSDictionary = [:] // Dictionary
var Sections : NSArray = [] // Array

itemsDict = [
["News"]:["a":"www.hello.co.uk","b":"www.hello.com"],
["Sport"]:["c":"www.hello.co.uk","d":"www.hello.com"],
    ]

    print (itemsDict)
```

This is how the structure of the dictionary looks like:

```
{
        (
        News
    ) =     {
        a = "www.hello.co.uk";
        b = "www.hello.com";
    };
        (
        Sport
    ) =     {
        c = "www.hello.co.uk";
        d = "www.hello.com";
    };
}
```

From the dictionary above I want to be able to populate an NSArray with only the - 
`[News,Sports]` elements. 
I've tried this and a few other methods but they just don't seem to cut it. My Swift skills are not that advanced and I hope this post make sense.

```
Sections = itemsDict.allKeysForObject(<#anObject: AnyObject#>)
```

Comment: Your dictionary structure looks a bit strange, with (nested) dictionaries both as keys and values. Are you sure you don't want an array of dictionaries?

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I fixed the Dictionary - Is it still possible to achieve this this way?

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of strings as your dictionary key? Seems like you just want the string there.  `"News":["Local News":"..."]` etc.

Comment: I thought like so would be a good way to create sections in a table view - update my code @MikeS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `Array` of all `String`s in your `Dictionary`'s keys, you can use the `allKeys` property of `NSDictionary` along with a `reduce` function, like so:

```
var itemsDict = [
    ["News"]:["a":"www.hello.co.uk","b":"www.hello.com"],
    ["Sport"]:["c":"www.hello.co.uk","d":"www.hello.com"],
]

let keys = (itemsDict.allKeys as [[String]]).reduce([], combine: +)

println(keys)
```

Outputs:

```
[News, Sport]
```

However, I don't see a good reason to use `Array`s of `String`s as your `Dictionary` keys. Instead, I'd just use `String`s as keys directly, like so:

```
var itemsDict = [
    "News":["a":"www.hello.co.uk","b":"www.hello.com"],
    "Sport":["c":"www.hello.co.uk","d":"www.hello.com"],
]
```

In which case, getting an `Array` of the `Dictionary`'s keys is as simple as:

```
let keys = itemsDict.keys.array
```

***Note:** I'm using the `keys` property here and the `allKeys` property earlier because this is a native Swift `Dictionary` while the earlier code is an `NSDictionary` due to its use of `NSArray`s for keys.*

Comment: Perfect thank you Mike - Now I know where I was going wrong, Exactly what I needed :)